# Animating a picture within border of div

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have some code that moves an image/element across the screen multiple times. The idea is that I'm trying to create a simple add bar with the image moving within the add bar, the  element acting as the border of the bar/the actual bar.

With my current setup, the image moves outside of the  element during animation despite being places within the /.

fiddle (may need to find new image) :http://jsfiddle.net/rwowf5j8/3/

```
<body onload="setInterval(function(){anim(document.getElementById('test'), 'left', 'px', 300, 800, 500)}, 600)">
<div id="Advert">
 <img src="JS.png" id="test">
</div>
</body>
<script>
function anim(elem,style,unit,from,to,time) {
    if( !elem) return;
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            var step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/time);
            elem.style[style] = (from+step*(to-from))+unit;
            if( step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
        },30);
    elem.style[style] = from+unit;
}
</script>
</body>


#Advert {
background-color: white;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
width: 500px;
height: 225px;
left: 300px;
}
#test {

position: absolute;
left: 140px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving your container relative positioning and hiding the overflowing elements will stop your issue:

```
#Advert {
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 225px;

  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

Because the container is now relative I've also removed the `left: 300px`.

http://jsfiddle.net/rwowf5j8/6/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/rwowf5j8/5/

add

```
#Advert {
    position: relative;
    /*left: 300px;*/
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also, left: 300px won't work unless you add position: relative.